# Meaning of "for 2 of every three weeks"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Someone asked me how to understand "for 2 of every 3 weeks" in the sentence below.

> If findings are negative, patients are given capecitabine **for 2 of every 3 weeks** until transplantation.

I said that's the contracted form of **for two (weeks) of every 3 weeks**. Is my explanation correct? If not, what's the meaning of it?

If so, shouldn't there be a definite article- "of **the** every 3 weeks"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expansion of the phrase is correct, the "two" is describing a particular number of weeks.

> If findings are negative, patients are given capecitabine for 2 **weeks** of every 3 weeks until transplantation.

More generally, in the construction "X of every Z [object]" both numbers refer to the same overall set of objects, and the second number Z refers to the size of the relevant subsets of those objects. The rest of the sentence explains what is happening with X objects from each subset.

The phrase "every three weeks" does not specify any particular set of three weeks (in fact, the opposite) so using a "the" article is ungrammatical.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you mind if I ask if you are a native English speaker?

Comment: I'm a native English speaker, and I find this answer entirely accurate. The expansion does the best job of explaining the use of "two of every three weeks." A more idiomatic expansion would be "for two out of every three weeks" or "for two weeks out of every three." We wouldn't typically say "for two weeks out of every three weeks" because "weeks" is clearly understood if you say it once. We might do so in a legal contract, though, because they prefer to leave nothing to context.

Comment: Yes, I am. @Cardinal

Answer (score 1):

I don't find the statement *patients are given capecitabine for 2 of every 3 weeks until transplantation* very clear, and it seems to be conflating uses of the construction **for...every**.

As I understand it, if there are twelve weeks until transplantation, there are four three-week spans involved. In each of those three-week periods, during two of the weeks in the period, capecitabine is administered.

Which two weeks? Any two of the three? The first and second, the first and third, the second and third?

We would normally use the phrase like this:

> I visit my uncle every three weeks.

I visit him, then two weeks go by where I don't visit him, and then I visit him again.  The visits occur on *some* day in week 1, 4, 7, 10, etc.  The reference is to a time *interval*. It is not a precise way of specifying time intervals.

However, it is not being used to express interval in your example, but *spans-and-intervals*.

Divide the time between now and the transplant into three-week periods, and for each of those periods, administer the drug in two of the three weeks of the span.